# Android library having trouble reading stream that openRawResource gives

Tags: java, android, file, plist

I'm using the plist library to load a plist file: http://code.google.com/p/plist/
I'm using code like so:

```
//InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.skillsanddrills)
    InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.skillsanddrills); //file name is skillsanddrills.plist
    NSDictionary rootDict;
    try {
    rootDict = (NSDictionary)PropertyListParser.parse(ins);
    ...
```

However I'm getting:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The given data is neither a
>   binary nor a XML property list. ASCII property lists are not
>   supported.

I don't believe this is the libraries fault because I got a similar error using another plist library and the file itself is just a plan XML struture. Why would Android be changing my plist files?
Any ideas on how to fix this?

The library also accepts files instead of streams. But can't work out how to create the file path to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the source code where it is crashing:

```
/**
 * Parses a property list from a file. It can either be in XML or binary format.
 * @param f The property list file
 * @return The root object in the property list
 * @throws Exception If an error occurred while parsing
 */
public static NSObject parse(File f) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    String magicString = new String(readAll(fis, 8), 0, 8);
    fis.close();
    if (magicString.startsWith("bplist00")) {
        return BinaryPropertyListParser.parse(f);
    } else if (magicString.startsWith("<?xml")) {
        return XMLPropertyListParser.parse(f);
    } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The given data is neither a binary nor a XML property list. ASCII property lists are not supported.");
    }
}
```

Maybe you should put your plist not in `xml` but the `raw` folder and load it like that:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.skillsanddrills)
```

If that fails put it in `asset` and load it like that:

```
getAssets().open("filename");
```

If that fails than your plist might be simply wrong formatted.

Comment: I thought I did getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.skillsanddrills)
I guess I didn't heh. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Ok this is odd, I get the same error when I add more plist files to the raw folder... Totally confused now.

Comment: Well I also fixed that, I had another file called laws.plist in both the raw and xml folder, when I deleted the xml folder version(no longer use the file), skillsanddrills.plist came right again. Very odd but at least it works again... heh